# how to make post requests in python/django?

Tags: python, django

as described in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing i want to make a post request to update a users status .How do i make post requests in python / django?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import urllib2

urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com', 'a=1&b=2')
```

will send a post request to http://example.com, with parameters a=1 and b=2

Answer (score 6):

Django has little to do with it, but [urrlib2.urlopen](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib2#urllib2.urlopen) is a simple enough way to `POST`.  Just call it with a second parameter `data` (the first one is the URL you're addressing) that has the *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* formatted data you're posting (as the docs say, use [urllib.urlencode](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) to encode a mapping, typically a dictionary, in that way).

Answer (score 0):

There is another way using python famous library Requests

```
import requests

data = {
  "username": "user",
  "password": "pass",
}

URL = 'http://example.com'
r = requests.post(URL, data=data)
```

PS: copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48751201/4539906)