# How can I do POST request in django?

Tags: python, django, http-post

with exception of *requests*, are there other ways for doing a POST HttpRequest?
I CAN ONLY USE DJANGO LIBS, so I cannot `import requests`.

In particular, I would like to pass the username and the password in the post request. something like:

```
data = {
    "username": "user",
    "password": "pass",
}
r = request.POST( data )
```

(please note that this code is just an example)

Anyone knows?

note: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: I cannot use `requests`. that request is for example.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36678494/2578808

Comment: thank you @RajSubit, it is good but unfortunately I can import only django libs, nothing else..

Comment: @ChiaraM what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @ozgur I have two systems that communicate among themselves; by the first one I have to send username and password to the second one (in a post request). I would already have done it if I could use `requests` ore some others libs. but I cannot, and I'm searching django libs for doing that

Comment: What do u mean by "I can import only django libs". urllib is a built-in python library that can be used in django

Comment: @RajSubit I mean that I can't import external packages.. 'chief' told me to use only django package; but, if it's built-in python library, than maybe it can solve my problem.. I try

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set url.

```
data = {
  "username": "user",
  "password": "pass",
}

URL = 'http://example.com'
r = requests.post(URL, data=data)
```

Comment: You right, I forgot to paste it. But I've said that I cannot use `requests`

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use requests, try using urllib2 and urllib.
What do you think about this?

```
post_data = {
  "username": "user",
  "password": "pass",
}
result = urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com', urllib.urlencode(post_data))
content = result.read()
```